# Доброго времени суток! Я начинающий разработчик, столкнулся с проблемой при написании цикла с запросами

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
getListIs(chatId, arrayUrl) {
  const HTTPrequest1C = require('./function_1c');

  var is_array = ['Элемент1'];

  arrayUrl.forEach((item_url) => {
    var is_list = HTTPrequest1C.getUser(chatId, item_url)
    is_list.then((result) => {
      is_array.push(result.is)
      console.log(is_array)
    })
  })
  console.log(is_array);
  return is_array
}
```

Циклом обхожу массив url адресов. На каждый делаю запрос, получаю промис и из него через then вытаскиваю  результат. Его добавляю к массиву. Вижу что массив есть и все что нужно в него добавилось. Но после цикла возвращается исходный массив с одним элементом "Элемент1" (return is_array). Видимо возврат идет раньше чем отрабатывает цикл. Прошу прощения за видимо глупый вопрос но как дождаться когда цикл закончить работу и вернуть массив со всеми элементами?

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Функцию getListIs нужно сделать асинхронной

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: И у forEach не очень хорошо с асинхронностью. Переделайте его в обычный цикл for и на каждой итерации дожидайтесь ответа

Comment: Отдельно хочется отметить названия переменных и использование var. Названтя `is*` подразумевают булевые значения. Переделайте `is_array` на, допустим, `resultArray`, так понятнее, зачем она. `is_list` во что то вроде `siteAnswer`. Ну и var на const замените, var устарел.

Comment: вот так должно быть https://pastebin.com/EyFyGb2G

Comment: Спасибо всем большое). У меня работает такой код 
async getUserArray(chatId, arrayUrl) {
    const resultArray = []

      for  (const item_url of arrayUrl) {
        let siteAnswer = await this.getUser(chatId, item_url)
      }
      return resultArray
  }
 Почему то добавив await перед обращением к сервису(как я понял я этим дожидаюсь окончания работы запроса к моему api) я в переменную siteAnswer получаю не промис а обычный массив как мне и  нужно(сервис возвращает строку)...И соответственно отпадает необходимость использования .then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем большое). У меня работает такой код
async getUserArray(chatId, arrayUrl) { const resultArray = [] for (const item_url of arrayUrl) { let siteAnswer = await this.getUser(chatId, item_url) } return resultArray }
Почему то добавив await перед обращением к сервису(как я понял я этим дожидаюсь окончания работы запроса к моему api) я в переменную siteAnswer получаю не промис а обычный массив как мне и нужно(сервис возвращает строку)...И соответственно отпадает необходимость использования .then